# Unable to install pysqlcipher3 using Yocto

Tags: build, yocto, sqlcipher, recipe

By using `devtool` I created a new recipe from the `pysqlcipher3` sources, however even though the build of a `core-image-minimal` doesn't throw any error, the library is not included in the final image.

I successfully compiled the sources in the host machine, also `sqlite3` and `sqlcipher` are correctly included in the building process of the image.

The following is the generated recipe

```
# pysqlcipher3_git.bb
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

SUMMARY = "DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLCIPHER 3.x"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/rigglemania/pysqlcipher3"
# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
#
# The following license files were not able to be identified and are
# represented as "Unknown" below, you will need to check them yourself:
#   LICENSE
LICENSE = "Zlib"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=94714ff78cc9f98add137dec4d3fa2c1"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/rigglemania/pysqlcipher3.git;protocol=https"

# Modify these as desired
#PV = "1.0.5+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "2370b08f6756215f5d4de95bc62f90dd6f52f420"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit setuptools3

# WARNING: the following rdepends are determined through basic analysis of the
# python sources, and might not be 100% accurate.
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python3-core"
```

`pysqlcipher3` is included in the `pn-buildlist` as well

Comment: did you actually add it to the image?

Comment: Yes by adding `pysqlcipher3` in `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`